# Mock firebase android applicattion

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in programming and i have to create a simple application with a database. I'm using Firebase realtime database and I have no idea how to do unit tests.

How can I mock database and push there some fake data to test?

Can you show me an example?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Firebase has an [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) that can be used for testing.  As written, this question is very broad.  You should be more specific about what you have tried and what isn't working for you.

Comment: I've got implemented method to add book and author to firebase realtime database. I don't know how to implement unit tests for that method.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: If you are just using the Realtime Database, one thing you can do is call goOffline() at the beginning of your tests. This will block all network activity, but local events will still fire due to latency compensation. This has limitations (e.g. Security Rules aren't enforced and transactions don't work outline), but may work depending on your use case.

Option 2: Check out https://github.com/azell/quasar-firebase

Option 3: Or for another approach which is not the same as mocking you could try environmental 'sandboxing'.

Instead of storing everything under the same root node you would create a different root node per environment.

For example:

```
{
DEV : { data : {'all_your_dev_data_lives_here'}}
PRODUCTION : { data : {'all_your_production_data_lives_here'} 
}
```

Within your android application you would build a configuration flag that lets you switch between 'DEV' and 'PRODUCTION'. If the flag is 'DEV' it would only ever write to the 'DEV' root node in Firebase and leave PRODUCTION untouched.

Comment: So if I choose first option I'm using references to my realtime database but calling goOffline() makes that changes will not be saved? And how should I call goOffline()? firebaseReferance.goOffline()?